# Is it possible to distribute an app that has files in NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know how to put files into a bundle. These are read-only; the user cannot modify them at runtime.

I know how to write files `NSDocumentDirectory` at runtime. These are read-write.

I know I can copy files from a bundle into `NSDocumentDirectory` the first time my app starts up.

I am wondering if there is a way to package writeable files directly with an application.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? If you need a bundled resource to be modifiable, copy it to the Documents folder, and modify it there. What problem are you trying to solve by modifying resources in your app bundle?

Comment: I'm new to iPhone development and have been wondering about this. Say I include a large database file (plist, sqlite, Core Data...) as initial data that eventually gets modified, so I have to copy it into a writable directory. Aren't I basically wasting space here? What if I include 50 megs of data e.g.? I end up using 100 megs, just because I had to create a writable copy.

Now I can't think of a specific example of why I might want to include data with my app and then modifybit all, but it doesn't seem entirely unlikely. I suppose I could create 2 data stores and merge them together e.g..

Comment: It's a tradeoff between user-experience and housekeeping costs. In my app users create multiple small files to hold their data. The first time they launch the app, I don't want them to see an empty list. So I want to give them a set of "starter" files which they can modify or erase. If they erase them, I don't want the files to magically come back. So I can copy files from a bundle to Documents directory the first time the app starts up, then add a file to Documents that says I've copied the files once and don't need to copy them again even if the Documents directory is empty. Housekeeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible to distribute an app with files in the document directory without knowing the user- and device-specific path to the document directory before runtime.